# How to split an 2D array, creating arrays from "row to row" values

Tags: python, numpy

I want to split an 2D array this way:

Example.

From this 4x4 2D array:

```
np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
```

Create these four 2x2 2D arrays:

```
np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
np.array([[9,10],[11,12]])
np.array([[13,14],[15,16]])
```

In a general case, from a NxN 2D array (square arrays) create 2D arrays of KxK shape, as many as possible.

Just to be more precise: to create the output array, not necessarily it will be made of all values from the row.

Example:

From a 2D 8x8 array, with values from 1 to 64, if I want to split this array in 2D 2x2 arrays, the first row from 8x8 array is a row from 1 to 8, and the first output 2D 2x2 array will be np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), and the second output 2D 2x2 array will be np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])... It continues until the last output 2D array, that will be np.array([[61,62],[63,64]]). Look that each 2D 2x2 array was not filled with all the values from the row (CORRECT).

There is a Numpy method that do this?

Comment: So, the output would be one multi-dimensional array of shape (4,2,2)?

Comment: Could you make your input (currently looks like 4 arrays) and output (looks like 8 arrays) less ambiguous? It's hard to know what you're looking for if it's unclear what **exactly** the input and output is.

Comment: @MSeifert ok, I have edited.

Comment: @Divakar no, the output would be four 2D array (2x2).

Comment: Okay, sorry for asking again. But now these are tuples of lists? Could you show how you would "create them by hand"? Or do you actually want tuples containing lists, or do you want arrays?

Comment: Sorry, I probably used tuple notation/syntax. How is matrix notation in Python?

Comment: `np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13, 14, 15, 16]])` is array notation (after doing `import numpy as np`).

Comment: @MSeifert, ok, thanks, I've edited.

Comment: I should have just entered the direct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your desired output, you need to reshape to a 3D array and then unpack the first dimension:

```
>>> inp = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
>>> list(inp.reshape(-1, 2, 2))
[array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]), 
 array([[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]), 
 array([[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]]), 
 array([[13, 14],
        [15, 16]])]
```

You can also unpack using `=` if you want to store the arrays in different variables instead of in one list of arrays:

```
>>> out1, out2, out3, out4 = inp.reshape(-1, 2, 2)
>>> out1
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

If you're okay with a 3D array containing your 2D 2x2 arrays you don't need unpacking or the `list()` call:

```
>>> inp.reshape(-1, 2, 2)
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10],
        [11, 12]],

       [[13, 14],
        [15, 16]]])
```

The `-1` is a special value for `reshape`. As the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) states:

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

---

If you want it more general, just take the square root of the row-length and use that as argument for `reshape`:

```
>>> inp = np.ones((8, 8))  # 8x8 array
>>> square_shape = 2
>>> inp.reshape(-1, square_shape, square_shape)  # 16 2x2 arrays

>>> square_shape = 4
>>> inp.reshape(-1, square_shape, square_shape)  # 4 4x4 arrays
```

Comment: excelent. I could put this in a "for" to work with each output array, right?

Comment: @Marco Yes, if you use the `list` or 3D `array` approach you can access each of the output arrays with a `for` loop over the list or array. :)

Comment: ok, thanks. Just to confirm your answer, to create the output array, not necessarily it will be made of all values from the row, right? Example: 
from a 2D 8x8 array, with values from 1 to 64, if I want to split this array in 2D 2x2 arrays, the first row from 8x8 array is a row from 1 to 8, and the first output 2D 2x2 array will be np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])... So, It was not filled with all the values from the row (CORRECT).

Comment: @Marco Sorry, but you lost me there. I thought your intention was to make a square array of the values of **one row**, not to create square arrays (potentially) spanning multiple rows of the original. Maybe your example was just too simple or I'm misunderstanding your intent.

Comment: yes, maybe the example was simple. I will edit the question, adding this above comment to clarify the question.

Comment: @Marco In that case just always use `.reshape(-1, 2, 2)` and don't bother about the `np.sqrt` thing I mentioned earlier.

Comment: thanks, I will test this code before accept this as a answer, ok?

Comment: Of course. Don't accept an answer if you don't know if it does what you asked for :)

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for something like [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape).

In your example:

```
numpy.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]).reshape(2,4)
>>>array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]])
```

Or, as suggested by @MSeifert, using -1 as final dimension will let numpy do the division by itself:

```
numpy.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]).reshape(2,-1)
>>>array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]])
```

Comment: Should also work with `.reshape(2, -1)`. That avoids hardcoding the "shape" of the second dimension.

Comment: In the example he hardcoded `4` as length of the second dimension. That will restrict it to arrays of size `8`. With `-1` it will work for all arrays that have a size that is divisible by 2. The comment asking for this information has been deleted but I'll keep it here in case it's of interest to anyone.

Comment: @Cédric Julien this code not get the desired output. From te example, If the input is a 2D 4x4 array, and if I want to split it in 2D 2x2 arrays, the first output array will be np.array([[1,2], [3,4]]). In your example, you get a 2D 2x4 array. The desired output from the first 2D 2x2 array would be no.array([[1,2], [3,4]]), not a single 2D 4x2 array.

Comment: @Marco : well, you changed/specified your question after my answer. I'm not sure you can automatically split into the maximum KxK arrays. You'll have to specify at least 1 dimension of the final shape.

Comment: Sure, i always define it. Example: output 2D 2x2 arrays, or 3x3, any square array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split it row wise, you may do np.reshape(arr,(2,2), order='C')
If you want to split it column wise, you may do not.reshape(arr,(2,2), order='F')